# Text area taking automatic html values under html

Tags: html, css, textarea

[image]   textarea automatically taking html markups from down in textarea value.

`<textarea placeholder="Group Name"  name='awesome' class='ring-1 ring-gray-300 px-4 py-2  outline-none rounded-md'></textarea>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Could you explain a bit more what the problem is and also please include code as code in the actual question not as an image - see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: From the info you supplied, there is no way to know why that markup is inside the textarea.